# Count number of distinct string with PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I am new in PIG and try to count the number of distinct countries in the following dataset (you can download it from [this link](http://help.mortardata.com/data/OlympicAthletes.csv)):

```
Athlete Country Year    Sport   Gold    Silver  Bronze  Total
Yang Yilin  China   2008    Gymnastics  1   0   2   3
Leisel Jones    Australia   2000    Swimming    0   2   0   2
Go Gi-Hyeon South Korea 2002    Short-Track Speed Skating   1   1   0   2
Chen Ruolin China   2008    Diving  2   0   0   2
Katie Ledecky   United States   2012    Swimming    1   0   0   1
Ruta Meilutyte  Lithuania   2012    Swimming    1   0   0   1
```

What I tried so far:

```
athletes = LOAD '/data/OlympicAthletes.csv' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',', 'YES_MULTILINE', 'NOCHANGE', 'SKIP_INPUT_HEADER') AS (athlete:chararray, country:chararray, year:int, sport:chararray, gold:int, silver:int, bronze:int, total:int);
distinct_countries= distinct (foreach athletes generate country);
country_count_try1 = COUNT(distinct_countries);
country_count_try2 = FOREACH distinct_countries GENERATE COUNT(country);
country_count_try3 = FOREACH (GROUP athletes country) GENERATE count(athletes.country) as total_country;
```

Comment: Try running dump and place what you got as outputs

Comment: All the outputs are empty

Comment: Is the input loaded ?. try dump for athletes

Comment: yes, input is loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group the whole dataset to count.

```
distinct_countries= distinct (foreach athletes generate country);
country_count_try4 = foreach (group distinct_countries all) generate COUNT(distinct_countries) as cnt;
```